# inserting newline in file stored on sd card

Tags: java, file

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
  Button btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

  btnSave.setOnClickListener(
          new OnClickListener()
          {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
              File file = new File("/sdcard/wpta_file1");
              FileWriter writer = null;
              try
              {

                writer = new FileWriter(file);
                writer.write(etContent.getText().toString() + "\n" + I_Status1.getText().toString() + "\n" + I_Status2.getText().toString() + "\n");
                writer.close();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();

                editor.putString("fpath", file.getPath());

                editor.commit();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Successfully saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                new conect().execute();

              }
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
            }

          }
  );
}
```

This is the above code i am using to store the data to file on sd card but i want write a new line into the text after each string it reads from the ui.

Comment: Well, what's wrong with the newlines you're writing right now?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of how the output looks like, and what it should be?

Comment: with the present code the output is " 122.87 100 101"

Comment: i need a output as "122.87 " on new line "100"   on new line "101

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `FileWriter`, try using `PrintWriter`, because `PrintWriter` has a `println` method which allows you to insert newline.

Comment: thank u so much tried using PrintWriter but not able to

Answer (score 1):

Javadocs for BufferedWriter [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).

writer.write(System.getProperty( "line.separator" ));